# My nested array won't print in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

```js
let array2 = ['Banana', ['Apples', ['Oranges'], 'Blueberries']];
document.write(array2[0][0]);
```

I wanted to print `Apples` in this array. When I tried `array2[0]` it prints `Banana` which is correct,  but when I make it `array2[0][0]` it prints `B`, when I make it like `array2[0][1]` it prints `a`. Seems like the string `Banana` became an array.

Comment: `Banana` is not an array, but a string, and you can access individual characters in strings with the same syntax that you use to access elements in an array - numeric brackets notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Apples` is in the second positioned array. So index should be `1`:

```js
let array2 = ['Banana', ['Apples', ['Oranges'], 'Blueberries']];
document.write(array2[1][0]);
```

> Seems like the string Banana became an array.

Please visit: [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> Characters in a string are indexed from left to right. The index of the first character is 0, and the index of the last character of a string called stringName is stringName.length - 1.

Comment: wow!That was fast! Thank you so much! I'm new in Javascript. May I know how come the apples become 1, isn't it part of Banana array? I would be so much grateful if you could explain it to me a bit, but if you can't, it's okay. Thank you very much!

Comment: @izee, array's are `0` based....so first item at index `0`, second item at `1`...and so on...

Comment: oh..I just thought the code was like this
array2=
['Banana',
  ['Apples', 
    ['Oranges'],
  'Blueberries']
];
it looks like a nested array to me..that's why I never thought the apple is one...